# Is it possible to transport a table of DataVerse from an environment to another environment？

Tags: powerapps, dataverse

I use PowerApps.
I have two envrionments: for development and for production operation.
I needed to add a column to a table in DataVerse（both development and production operation environment have the same table.）
I decide to add a column in development environment and import the table(solution) to production operation.
(I can be updating, not creating because production operation environment already has the same named table.)

1. I add a column to the table in the development environment.
2. I want to reflect the table structure of development environment to the table in production operation environment.
3. I made a solution which include the table that contains the new column in development environment and exported the solution.
4. Next I will import the solution to the production operation environment.

I am worried about deleting the data of table in the production operation environment.
Will the data of the table in the production operation environment remain after importing the solution which comes from development environment?
Are there any points I need to care about?

I now made solution. but I'm worried about whether data in production environment has been gone, so I do not import the solution to production environment yet

1. I add a column to the table in the development environment.
2. I want to reflect the table structure of development environment to the table in production operation environment.
3. I made a solution which include the table that contains the new column in development environment and exported the solution.
4. Next I will import the solution to the production operation environment.

Answer (score 0):

Feel free to import. The data won't go anywhere unless you are deleting the column in development and use managed solutions to bring changes to your production. If you are nervous you always get a backup of the environment before performing such kind of operations - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/admin/backup-restore-environments